# Modal displays strangely with bootstrap framework

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

On a web page who have many tab, i have a input box who do a search via a ajax call.

If there is no result, i would like to display a modal dialog box.

```
<div role="tabpanel">

<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-right">

            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="inactiveLodger"> Locataire inactif
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button id="lodgerSearch" type="button"  class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </nav>


        <div class="modal fade" id="modalEmptyResult">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                <h3>Résultat de recherche</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Aucun résultat ne correspondant à votre requête</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn">Fermer</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
...
```

```
 $('#lodgerSearch').on('click', function (e) {

        var inactiveLodger = $('#inactiveLodger').is(':checked');

        debugger;

        var searchParam = $('#srch-term').val();
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/lodgers/search";
        if (searchParam != "") {
            url = url + "?searchTerm=" + searchParam;
        }

        if (inactiveLodger == true) {
            url = url + "?inactiveLodger=true";
        }

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                debugger;
                if (data.length == 0) {
                    $("#lodgerSearchResult").empty();
                    $('#modalEmptyResult').modal('show');
                } else {
                    $("#lodgerSearchResult").empty().append(template(data));
                }


            },
            error: function (jqXHR, status) {
                // error handler
                alert("error " + jqXHR + " -  " + status);
            }
        });
        // e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Like we can see on the picture, we can see the dialog box, but it's seem transparent.

[image]

I created a basic example with similar problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/m7eop6k1/

Strange with jquery 1.9.1 that work... but not with latest release of jquery.

Comment: You need to instantiate the modal before you can call `open` on it

Comment: Incorrect html inside modal (missing divs). check http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: @idan, if you check some example provided by bootstrap, it don't seem to have anything more to do.

Comment: @roberttrudel when you have a case similar to their examples (triggering button) you don't need much, just some annotations (which are missing in your sample code) but your case is different because you want to show the modal programmatically, so you have to instantiate it first. I'll show an example once I'm near a computer

Comment: Fixed the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cjmdtc0o/ the jQuery didn't work for some reason... Not sure exactly since I'm on mobile